# java ConcurrentModificationException, how to solve

Tags: java

```
 for (String check : partresult) {
        int count=checkDiff(check,endword);
        if (count < min) {
            min = count;
            Iterator itr = res.iterator();
            while(itr.hasNext()) {
                Object elem=itr.next();
                if (checkDiff(elem.toString(), endword) != min)
                    res.remove(elem);
            }
            res.add(check);
        }
    }
```

for this piece of code, I have java.util.ConcurrentModificationException in the res.remove(elem). I already used an iterator, so really do not know what is wrong, hope somebody could help. thanks

Comment: You're not removing the element with the iterator. Don't do this. You'll also want to search this site before asking questions that likely have been asked many times before, because often the you'll find the answer quickly that way. For example: [site search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+ConcurrentModificationException+arraylist+remove)

Comment: `"I already used an iterator"` -- but again you're not removing with the iterator. Again, review these many, many, many [similar questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+ConcurrentModificationException+arraylist+remove).